# SSIS error information

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have 15-20 data task each in their own sequence container in a single SSIS. 
Is it possible to catch the data task or sequence which failed and email that details (task name or sequence name, cause for failure) to a user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create a sequence level `OnError` handler and do whatever you need to do in there. The error details are available as system variables.

Answer (score 0):

WE only have one failure email at the top of the food chain. What we do is catch the task name in it. the System::SourceName variable contains the task that failed.